# How to break long single word in <td> using CSS?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

in a `td` of a `table` i have a very long single word "**Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis**" and i want to reduce the width of `table` but unable to do because of this long word in one of the `td` i can break this word by giving `<br />` but is there any CSS way to break this word according to available space. without giving **line break** or edit anything in HTML.

Answer (score 33):

Try the following:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
white-space: normal;
```

word-wrap is css3 (however it works in IE). You might not be able to get it working in older browsers however.

Comment: I believe `word-wrap` support goes all the way back to IE5!

Comment: @BenRowe, should add `table {table-layout:fixed}`. Or try this: `td {word-wrap: break-word; word-break: break-all}`

Comment: you may need to add this `hyphens: auto;`

Answer (score 22):

The following works for me:

```
    word-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-all;
    white-space: normal;
```

Comment: Also need to change the display of the element (a or span) to be block or inline-block

Answer (score 9):

Try the following code for break word if there is not any space.

```
word-wrap: break-word;
word-break: break-all;
```

Answer (score 7):

```
td span{display:block;width:your_max_width_here.px}

<td><span>Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis</span></td>
```

Comment: +1 thx for this solution. is there any possibility of other way through pure CSS bcoz table is auto generated by CMS so i can't add `<span>`

Comment: @metal-gear-solid So wrap your value first with 'max-width'd span in your data source before you show it to html.

Answer (score 4):

**try my code --**

With Table body

```
table>tbody>tr>th{
    word-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-all;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Without Table body

```
table>tr>th{
    word-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-all;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I've tried different combinations of solutions found here and in other pages but it never worked as expected for me - the short words were split even if they had space on the line below and it looked goofy.

Finally I've found this compromise:

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    word-wrap: break-word; /* IE */
}
```

If you want to treat your rows equally, it works best.

Answer (score 1):

Following code should work;

```
td {word-break: break-all}
```

Answer (score 1):

The modern (post IE) way is:

```
td {
  overflow-wrap: anywhere;
}
```

Except that – as of this writing – it is not supported in Safari. [Stay tuned.](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_overflow-wrap_anywhere)

[Here is a test.](https://jsfiddle.net/andraaspar/g93wznj8/)

Answer (score 0):

I found when you have a mixture of content in the cell, some long single words mixed in with other short words, that `word-break: break-word;` works best.  It will break on whitespace when possible. Although this doesn't appear to be supported in IE11. If you set break-all to either of the mentioned properties, it will always break within a word (unless it's lucky enough to be on a space).